# Selecting next and previous list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I am working on a simple image gallery with a larger picture displayed above a line of thumbnails below.  I have set the initial opacity of each thumbnail to 0.3 by using a css rule targeting the li.  Using javascript I want to change the opacity of the thumbnail that is currently selected to 1, but keep the rest set at 0.3.

I have managed to change the current thumbnail's opacity from 0.3 to 1 but what I cannot figure out how to do is change the previous (or next) thumbnails opacity back to 0.3.

For example, if thumbnail #3 is currently selected I want all the remaining 5 thumbnails to revert back to their orignal opacity setting of 0.3

I have put some of my code into the below link so you can get an idea of what I going on about.

div class="thumbnails">

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='#' class='thumb' id="thumb_1"></a></li>
    <!-- MORE FOLLOW -->
</ul>
```

```
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    currentPic++;
    $(".thumbnails ul li:nth-child(" + currentPic + ")").animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    });
});
```

Full code sample: http://jsfiddle.net/nqKJw/

Comment: @GrailsGuy I have taken the liberty of doing so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function where you are setting the opacity of the desired thumbnail to 1, first set **all** thumbnails to an opacity of .3:

```
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    $(".thumbnails ul li").animate({
        "opacity": "0.3"
    });
    currentPic++;
    $(".thumbnails ul li:nth-child(" + currentPic + ")").animate({
        "opacity": "1"
    });
});
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/nqKJw/1/

Comment: genius.  Thanks for the help.  Don't know why I did't think of that!

Comment: @user1563944 Might I suggest you accept an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the opacity value of the current item before changing the current item

```
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
  $(".thumbnails ul li:nth-child(" + currentPic + ")").animate({
      "opacity": ".3"
  });

  currentPic++;

  $(".thumbnails ul li:nth-child(" + currentPic + ")").animate({
      "opacity": "1"
  });
});
```

And similarly for prevBtn

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqKJw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/nqKJw/3/)'s a nice solution using the `.current` class

CSS:

```
.current{ opacity:1 !important; }
```

Jquery:

```
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
    var nextThumb = $('.thumbnails .current').removeClass('current').next();
    nextThumb = nextThumb.length?nextThumb:$('.thumbnails li:first');
    $(nextThumb).addClass('current');
});

$("#prevBtn").click(function() {
    var nextThumb = $('.thumbnails .current').removeClass('current').prev();
    nextThumb = nextThumb.length?nextThumb:$('.thumbnails li:last');
    $(nextThumb).addClass('current');
});​
```